# Python with Vim

Tags: python, vim

I'm trying to use python with Vim. When I create a .py file and try to execute it using the .<FileName>, I get the following error:

```
 line 2  ~  
 |SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe1' in file C:\Users\Nilton Schum~ 
 |acher F\Desktop\Udemy Python\recebendo_dados_usuario.py on line 3, but no enco~  
 |ding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

This is how my test.py file looks:

```
"""
This are notes
"""
print("Whats your name?")
```

Comment: It appears you're using Python 2 - must you? I strongly recommend upgrading to Python 3, but if you insist on using 2, you'll need to declare an encoding at the start of the file, as explained in the page mentioned in the error message.

Comment: What do you mean by "using the .<FileName>"? That doesn't sound like how you're supposed to run Python.

Comment: @Grismar How can I update to python 3? When I type python in the console I get python 3.8.5

Comment: @Grismar: No, that looks like a Python 3 error message to me. You can tell because it says "Non-UTF-8" instead of "Non-ASCII".

Comment: OK, then it sounds like you have Python 3 already, but perhaps that's not the version of Python launched by whatever editor you're launching it from. You should provide some more detail on exactly what you do when you edit and launch a script. It's also possible your editor is using an encoding Python does not expect and it tries to interpret it as UTF - check your editor's settings and ensure it writes UTF-8 to the .py

Answer (score 1):

Just wondering whether you've set the encoding in your vimrc to utf-8, if not try adding a line to `~/.vimrc` of `set encoding=utf-8`. This is solely based on the error message, if the error changes, comment below!

EDIT: Actually it seems you're on Windows, I have no clue where the vimrc would be here, but I'm sure this is easy enough to find!

Comment: Quick search found this, would recommend checking this if you can't find .`vimrc`:
[here](https://superuser.com/questions/86246/where-should-the-vimrc-file-be-located-on-windows-7)

Comment: I have foung the vimrc file, since I have some changes on it, I added the following line to the .vimrc file, but still getting the erro

Comment: Have you restarted vim after editing the vimrc file, and have you tried overwriting the file after adding the line?

Comment: Yep, Restarted Vim editor but still getting this:
```
  File "C:\Users\Nilton Schumacher F\Desktop\Udemy Python\recebendo_dados_usuario.py", line 2
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe1' in file C:\Users\Nilton Schumacher F\Desktop\Udemy Python\recebendo_dados_usuario.py on line 3, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Comment: The following command worked: :e! ++enc=utf8, to set it into my vimrc, i will only need to set e! ++enc=utf8?

Comment: Yeah I think so, actually apologies earlier, you need to save the file in utf-8, which requires this in `.vimrc`: `set fileencoding=utf-8`